# Trying to create attribute group under class in Linux kernel driver

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am writing a driver for a peripheral with multiple channels that can be independently configured. I would like to expose these through sysfs.

I have created a simple test driver to work through the sysfs setup and encountered a problem: I can create a device class and can create attributes associated with it with no problem, however I would like to create a sub class for each channel and apply a group of attributes to each channel.

Here is a code snippet from my a simple test driver:

```
static struct class *testClass;

static ssize_t __set_active(struct class *cls, struct class_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t len)
{
        return len;
}

static size_t __show_active(struct class *cls, struct class_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
        return 0;
}
static CLASS_ATTR(testActive, 0644, __show_active, __set_active);

static struct attribute *test_attrs[] = {
        &class_attr_testActive.attr,
        NULL
};

static struct attribute_group channel_group_attrs = {
        .name = "channel",
        .attrs = test_attrs
};

static int __init groupTest_init(void)
{
        int error = 0;

        pr_debug("Loading test module...\n");

        testClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "testClassBase");
        if (IS_ERR(testClass))
        {
                printk(KERN_ERR "Could not create the class!\n");
                return PTR_ERR(testClass);
        }

        pr_debug("Setting up group under %s...\n", testClass->dev_kobj->name);
        if (sysfs_create_group(testClass->dev_kobj, &channel_group_attrs) )
        {
                printk(KERN_ERR "Could not create attribute group!\n");
        }

        pr_debug("Module loaded!\n");

        return error;
}
```

The main issue seems to be the kobject being returned from testClass->dev_kobj points to char devices (which is where the group is creates) instead of the class.

I have greped the kernel source for a while and I can't seem to find a way to grab the kobject for the class.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want a directory in sysfs for each channel in which you could add the attributes .i.e sysfs entries for a given channel ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. And given the number of attributes that are common to each channel, I was planning on using attribute groups to simplify the driver (which is new to me).